# read on a pipe blocks until program running at end of pipe terminates - Windows

Tags: c, linux, ipc, popen, blocking

I have a sample program that outputs a line of text every second.  In the test program below, this program writes some text to `stdout` then waits 1 second and repeats 20 times.

I have another program which uses `popen` (`_popen` on Windows) to open a pipe for reading from the program.  I then use `fgets` to read data.  The problem I have is that the `fgets` blocks until the program terminates.  Then I get all the output, all 20 lines, in one go.  I want to get the output a line at a time, then ok for `fgets` to block until next line ready.  The reason is I plan to use this on a program that will be constantly running, outputting text, e.g. like the use of `tail`.

If I run this code example on a program that outputs some text all in one go and exits then it works fine.

Why does `fgets` block?  The test program does print some text immediately, so why doesn't `fgets` read this first line of text immediately?

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

void execute(const char* cmd) {
    char buffer[128] = { 0 };
    FILE* pipe = _popen(cmd, "r");

    if (!pipe) {
        printf("popen() failed!\n");
        return;
    }

    while (!feof(pipe)) {
        if (fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != nullptr)
            printf("%s", buffer);
    }

    int rc = _pclose(pipe);

    if (rc != EXIT_SUCCESS) { // return code not 0
        printf("pclose exit failure: %d\n", rc);
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: pipe_test.exe <program>\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    execute(argv[1]);
}
```

The program run, `helloworld.exe`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        printf("Hello World %d\n", i);
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Writing to a pipe is buffered by default. Either turn off buffering with `setvbuf()` or call `fflush(stdout)` after each `printf()`.

Comment: @Barmar I tried setvbuf(pipe, NULL, _IONBF, 128); after creating the pipe but had no effect

Comment: @Barmar in the called program flush(stdout) means get immediate output.  Not as convenient because I would prefer to work with unmodified called programs, but gives me a workaround.  I thought \n in the printf in the called program is same as flush?

Comment: @AngusComber printf will flush on newline but only when going to real stdout device. If it is redirected then it is buffered  to improve throughput.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: @AngusComber `stdout` is line-buffered when connected to a terminal, fully-buffered when connected to anything else. If you can't modify the child program, the workaround is to use the `unbuffer` utility to run it; this comes with the Expect tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does `fgets` block?

Because it's waiting for the children to output something.

> The test program does print some text immediately, so why doesn't `fgets` read this first line of text immediately?

It actually does *not* print text immediately. The problem here, as [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) notices, is that writing to a pipe is buffered (and not *line* buffered) by the C standard library implementation. This buffering happens in your child program (`helloworld`), not in your parent program (`pipe_test`).

From your parent program, you have no control over what the children spawned through `popen()` will do, therefore if the child output is buffered like in this case, the only thing you can do (without modifying the child's code) is to wait until the buffer is flushed to the pipe.

In order to get the output sooner, you would have to modify the children's code to manually call [`fflush()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) or use [`setvbuf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html) to disable buffering:

```
int main() {
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0); // Disable buffering on stdout.

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        printf("Hello World %d\n", i);
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

There's really not much else you can do.